# How to pause a CADisplayLink?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cadisplaylink

I have a problem in my app. What I want to happened is when I click button2, it disappears and stops moving. What's happening now is that when I click button2, it disappears but doesn't stop moving (even while its hidden).Any help? Code:

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var label2: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet var label3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
@IBAction func button3(sender: UIButton) {
    label.hidden = false
button2.hidden = true
}
@IBOutlet var button4: UIButton!
@IBAction func button5(sender: UIButton) {
button4.hidden = true
label2.hidden = false
}
@IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
   label.hidden = true
    label2.hidden = true
   button2.hidden = false
      button2.frame = CGRectMake(120, 400, 100, 100)
    let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink:")
    displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 2 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
        self.button4.hidden = false
    self.button4.frame = CGRectMake(120, 400, 100, 100)
    let displayLink1 = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink1:")
        displayLink1.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)}
    }
func handleDisplayLink(displayLink: CADisplayLink) {
    var buttonFrame = button2.frame
    buttonFrame.origin.y += -2
    button2.frame = buttonFrame
    if button2.frame.origin.y <= 50 {
        displayLink.invalidate()
        label3.hidden = false
        button2.hidden = true
    }
}
func handleDisplayLink1(displayLink1: CADisplayLink) {
    var button4Frame = button4.frame
    button4Frame.origin.y += -2
    button4.frame = button4Frame
    if button4.frame.origin.y <= 50 {
        displayLink1.invalidate() 
        label3.hidden = false
        button4.hidden = true
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  label.hidden = true
    button2.hidden = true
   label2.hidden = true
    button4.hidden = true
   label3.hidden = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.  
}
```

Thank you. Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exceedingly confusing because it's unclear as to the relationship between the two outlets called `button2` and `button4` and the `@IBAction` methods called `button1`, `button3`, and `button5`? How many buttons do you actually have? Two? Four? Five? And what these various labels? If they're not part of the question, they shouldn't be included in the code snippet.

But if it's `button3` or `button5` that's getting called, then yes, those hide the button, but don't `invalidate` the display link, so the display link will progress. If you want it to stop the display link, then you have to call `invalidate`:

```
var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
var displayLink1: CADisplayLink?

@IBAction func button3(sender: UIButton) {
    label.hidden = false
    button2.hidden = true
    displayLink?.invalidate()
    displayLink = nil
}

@IBAction func button5(sender: UIButton) {
    button4.hidden = true
    label2.hidden = false
    displayLink1?.invalidate()
    displayLink1 = nil
}
```

This obviously means that `button5` should be using these properties, not using local variables for `displayLink` and `displayLink1`:

```
@IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
    label.hidden = true
    label2.hidden = true
    button2.hidden = false
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(120, 400, 100, 100)
    // NB: No `let` on the next line
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink:")
    displayLink?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 2 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.button4.hidden = false
        self.button4.frame = CGRectMake(120, 400, 100, 100)
        // NB: No `let` on the next line
        self.displayLink1 = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink1:")
        self.displayLink1?.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    }
}
```

A few additional observations:

1. If you're using auto-layout, you should be very wary about just adjusting the `frame` of these controls. In auto-layout, if you happen to do anything to trigger the constraints engine to be applied (e.g. update the `text` of these labels), the controls will move back to where the constraints defined them to be.
2. You're changing the `frame` of these controls, moving them 2 points per call. That's might end up with stuttering or changing of speeds of the animation UI as your app gets more complicated. You shouldn't update a fixed amount per call of the display link handler, but rather use some time based functions to determine how much time has elapsed and calculate the new coordinates from that.
3. I personally wouldn't use display links for this kind of stuff. I would just use the standard `UIView.animateWithDuration`, and then when I wanted to stop button2 from moving, I would:

   ```
   let currentButton2Frame = button2.layer.presentationLayer()!.frame
   button2.layer.removeAllAnimations()
   button2.frame = currentButton2Frame
   ```

   This identifies where it is, mid-animation, stops the animation, and resets the `frame` to the coordinates previously identified. This avoids the complexities of display links.

Comment: For your third observation, would this work if I had a timer running at the same time or will it update the frames and not be able to move?

Comment: The animation happens seamlessly in parallel with the timer. The only trick, which I tried to describe, is when you stop the animation in your timer, just examine the presentation layer to figure out where it was midflight, and "move" it to that same location, so it stays where it was when you stopped the animation in the timer's handler.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you were talking about but when I try to run the app, this shows :  unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value... What should I do (should I make something optional?)

Comment: @AntonO. No, that's a completely different issue. That means that you have an optional variable, you are unwrapping it (either with the explicit use of `!` or because the optional variable was defined to be implicitly unwrapped), but that variable is still `nil`, resulting in the error you describe. So, you have to go through the lines of code one-by-one, and find the line that is unwrapping the optional that is still `nil`. Then figure out why that variable is `nil` even though you thought it shouldn't be, or else add the conditional binding that will gracefully unwrap only if it's not `nil`.

Comment: Perhaps check that your outlets are not `nil` and that `presentationLayer()` didn't return `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a reference to the display links you create in your button click handler. So create class level properties for them:

```
@IBAction func button5(sender: UIButton) {
    button4.hidden = true
    label2.hidden = false
}

// new code here:
var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
var displayLink1: CADisplayLink?
```

Then invalidate them before you create them, in case an instance already exists:

```
@IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
   displayLink?.invalidate()
   displayLink1?.invalidate()

   displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink:")
   displayLink1 = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "handleDisplayLink1:")

   displayLink = 
   label.hidden = true
   label2.hidden = true
   button2.hidden = false

   // ... rest of your method
}
```